# Subscription class not found: Rails ActionCable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am trying to add an instant messaging function to my Rails 7 app. I keep getting the following error:

```
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-04-25 03:28:15 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Subscription class not found: "ConversationsChannel"
```

I have this in app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:

```
class ConversationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def subscribed
    conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    stream_for conversation
  end
end
```

My div for displaying the conversation:

```
<div class="well w-full md:ml-5 flex-1 h-4/5" data-channel-subscribe="conversations" data-conversation-id="<%= @conversation.id %>">
  #rest of html
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
import consumer from "/channels/consumer";

  $(function() {
    $('[data-channel-subscribe="conversations"]').each(function(index, element) {
      var $element = $(element),
          conversation_id = $element.data('conversation-id'),
          messageTemplate = $('[data-role="message-template"]');

      consumer.subscriptions.create(
        {
          channel: "ConversationsChannel",
          conversation_id: conversation_id
        },
        {
          received: function(data) {

        if (data.sender_id === gon.current_user_id) {
          var ul = document.getElementById("list");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.classList.add('me');
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.body));
          ul.appendChild(li);
        } else {
          var ul = document.getElementById("list");
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.classList.add('him');
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.body));
          ul.appendChild(li);
        }

        document.getElementById('body').value = ''
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages-scroll");
        $("#messages-scroll").scrollTop($("#messages-scroll")[0].scrollHeight);

      }
    }
  );
});


});
```

Am I missing something obvious? I can't figure it out so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your channel Ruby code in `conversation_channel.rb` (singular) or `conversations_channel.rb` (plural)?

Comment: the file name is singular, and the class is plural

Comment: Does using a plural file name (or singular class name) solve the issues? Rails typically expects the file and class names to reflect each other. There may be some autoloading that’s not working due to the inconsistency.